# How to implement a content switcher or basic carousel without using IDs in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, semantic-markup, nodelist, queryselector

I'm not pro in JavaScript, I'm still learning. On my site, there is a hero section that has a title, paragraph, and is filled with a picture.

```html
<div class="slider" style="background-image:url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400');">
  <div class="slider-title">Main Text 1</div>
  <div class="slider-title display-none">Main Text 2</div>
  <div class="slider-title display-none">Main Text 3</div>

  <div class="slider-lead">Paragraph text 1</div>
  <div class="slider-lead display-none">Paragraph text 2</div>
  <div class="slider-lead display-none">Paragraph text 3</div>
</div>

<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="hero-switch">
    <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/331860/dot.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="hero-switch">
    <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/331860/dot.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="hero-switch">
    <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/331860/dot.svg">
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to switch divs with 3 "bullet" buttons - each is responsible for showing relevant content (1st bullet = 1st div with Main Text1, Paragraph Text1 and 1st url background, 2nd bullet = 2nd div with Main text 2 and so on).

I know that I can assign specific IDs to each "bullet" button and add event listener but I feel that way is not too good.

Thanks for help!

I'm looking for solution in pure JS.

I have tried the forEach function but i don't know exactly how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see which questions are on-topic on this site.

Comment: Sorry !! your question is not clear are you looking for something like tabs on bootstrap but in vanilla js ?
Please clear up your question.
After looking at bootstrap tabs (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/)

Comment: Though an approach which structurally separates the navigation from the contents is ok, structurally separating content which belongs together in my opinion is not. Why not combine/collect content of a certain context/subject into containers, one container per context/subject?

Comment: Why don't you want IDs or something like jQuery? There are two ways, one with something like `document.getQuerySelector(".className")` and the other ones being `document.getElementsByClassName("className")[i]`, `i` being the the identifier starting at `0`. [query selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) [class name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: @sh4kr ... From both so far provided answers / approaches are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the child index of the `.hero-switch` within its parent. With this index, you can loop over all the titles and leads and toggle the `display: none` style rule.

**Note:** It is not necessary, but you should group all the titles and leads, or group each pair of title and lead. This adds some organization to the markup.

```js
const getChildIndex = (el) => [...el.parentNode.children].indexOf(el);

const handleNavigation = (e) => {
  const index = getChildIndex(e.target.closest('.hero-switch'));
  const titles = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-title');
  const leads = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-lead');
  for (let i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    titles[i].classList.toggle('d-none', i !== index);
    leads[i].classList.toggle('d-none', i !== index);
  }
};

document.querySelectorAll('.hero-switch').forEach(hs =>
  hs.addEventListener('click', handleNavigation));
```

```css
.slider {
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: 8rem;
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400');
  background-size: cover;
}

.slider-title,
.slider-lead {
  text-shadow: 0.05rem 0.05rem 0.1rem #FFF;
}

.slider-title {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.hero-switch:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div>
      <div class="slider-title">Main Text 1</div>
      <div class="slider-title d-none">Main Text 2</div>
      <div class="slider-title d-none">Main Text 3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="slider-lead">Paragraph text 1</div>
      <div class="slider-lead d-none">Paragraph text 2</div>
      <div class="slider-lead d-none">Paragraph text 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="hero-switch"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/331860/dot.svg"></div>
      <div class="hero-switch"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/331860/dot.svg"></div>
      <div class="hero-switch"><img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/331860/dot.svg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding my earlier above comment ...

> *"Though an approach which structurally separates the navigation from the contents is ok, structurally separating content which belongs together in my opinion is not. Why not combine/collect content of a certain context/subject into containers, one container per context/subject? "*

... how about an approach then which incorporates following ...

- does display all content correctly without JavaScript enabled for it uses markup which groups related content.
- does use semantic markup including a radio-list for the selectable content options (which makes it keyboard navigable).
- uses kind of a component based approach where script initialization does not depend on class names but on component specific [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) attributes.

The implementation is straightforward

1. two node lists are queried

   - one for the content options (the OP's bullet list)
   - one for the to be presented contents.
2. each selection node gets assigned a single change handler where the latter was created as a method with bound data (the two node lists).
3. upon this bound data and the event object's [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) one can manage the correct states for both the to be displayed and hidden contents.
4. there will be a default selection/display of the first content item.
5. the component gets assigned an `initialized` class name which triggers the correct display mode for enabled JavaScript (until then all content is on display).

```js
function handleContentSwitchFromBoundData({ currentTarget }) {
  const { selectorList, contentList } = this;
  const selectedIndex = selectorList
    .findIndex(selectorNode =>
      selectorNode === currentTarget
     );
  contentList
    .forEach(({ classList }) =>
      classList.remove('selected')
    );
  contentList[selectedIndex]
    .classList.add('selected');
}

function initializeContentSwitchComponent(rootNode) {
  const selectorList = [...rootNode
    .querySelectorAll('[data-content-selector]')];
  const contentList = [...rootNode
    .querySelectorAll('[data-content-item]')];

  const handleContentSwitch = handleContentSwitchFromBoundData
    .bind({ selectorList, contentList });

  selectorList
    .forEach(selectorNode =>
      selectorNode
        .addEventListener('change', handleContentSwitch)
    );

  // 1st item default selection
  selectorList[0].click();

  rootNode
    .classList
    .add('initialized');
}

function main() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('[data-content-switch]')
    .forEach(initializeContentSwitchComponent);
}
main();
```

```css
[data-content-switch] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px 45px 20px;
  background: #666 url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400');
  background-size: cover;
}

[data-content-switch] ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
[data-content-switch] > ol {
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 0.05rem 0.05rem 0.1rem #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

[data-content-switch] > nav {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  text-align: center;
}
[data-content-switch] > nav > ol {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
[data-content-switch] > nav > ol li {
  display: inline-block;
}

[data-content-switch] [data-content-options] {
  display: none;
}
[data-content-switch].initialized [data-content-options] {
  display: unset;
}

[data-content-switch] [data-content-item] {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
[data-content-switch].initialized [data-content-item] {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
[data-content-switch].initialized [data-content-item].selected {
  position: relative;
  left: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<article data-content-switch>
  <nav data-content-options>
    <ol>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="hero" data-content-selector />
          <!-- <span class="label"> some label text </span> //-->
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="hero" data-content-selector />
          <!-- <span class="label"> some label text </span> //-->
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="hero" data-content-selector />
          <!-- <span class="label"> some label text </span> //-->
        </label>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </nav>

  <ol data-target-content>
    <li data-content-item>
      <p>Main Text 1</p>
      <p>Paragraph text 1</p>
    </li>
    <li data-content-item>
      <p>Main Text 2</p>
      <p>Paragraph text 2</p>
    </li>
    <li data-content-item>
      <p>Main Text 3</p>
      <p>Paragraph text 3</p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</article>
```